# Google Analytics MCF API: Setting MCF Look-Back window via API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How to set the look-back window in the Google Analytics Multi Channel Funnel API?

In the Google Analytics UI there is the possibility to set the look-back window for the Multi Channel Funnel Transaction tracking. However, I cannot figure out how to set the attribute in MCF Reporting API.

Any ideas how to set the lookback window using the [MCF reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/reference)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API uses a non-adjustable 30-day lookback window (15/12/2015, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/mcfDevGuide).